# How do I insert a string into another string in Lua?

Tags: string, lua

Is there a function in Lua that returns a string inserted into another one on given position?

For example `string.insert(str1, str2, pos)`.

Using it: `string.insert('Hello World!', 'My ', 6)` becomes`Hello My World!` and so on.

Comment: `str1 = str1:gsub("()", {[pos]=str2})`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such function in the standard Lua library. But it's easy to write one:

```
function string.insert(str1, str2, pos)
    return str1:sub(1,pos)..str2..str1:sub(pos+1)
end
```

Note how it automatically handles negative positions (*), which count from the end of the string, as most other string functions do.

(*) it needs a small change to make `pos=-1` work.